# UML State Diagram - Enter State without invoking Entry Functions

Tags: uml

I'm trying to draw a UML state diagram with these features:

1. State A transitions to State B on Trigger X
2. State B has an Entry Action "OnEntry"
3. When in State B and you receive Trigger Y,
   you stay in State B (without invoking the Entry Action)

I want to include Trigger Y in the state diagram so it's explicit that it's valid during State B.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to confess that state machines are not really my strength. However,

[image]

trigger `Y` does not exit state `B`. Thus the state stays the same. And thus the `onEntry` will not be executed.

The specs state (p. 307):

> **14.2.3.4.3 State entry, exit, and doActivity Behaviors**
>   A State may have an associated entry Behavior. This Behavior, if defined, is executed whenever the State is entered through an external Transition. In addition, a State may also have an associated exit Behavior, which, if defined, is executed whenever the State is exited.

Comment: Cool!  So maybe I have the opposite problem ... what if I have another trigger "Z" that leaves B, re-enters B, and SHOULD trigger "onEntry"?

Comment: Each transition can have it's own behavior. So you would just call `onEntry` as part of this behavior. That's it.